# Color a UILabel with attributedText

Tags: ios, uitableview, swift, twitter

Hi I'm doing a twitter app,and I want to color hashtags,usernames,and urls
Here is the class with my cell

```
class TweetTableViewCell: UITableViewCell
{
var tweet: Tweet? {
    didSet {
        updateUI()
    }
}

@IBOutlet weak var tweetProfileImageView: UIImageView!
@IBOutlet weak var tweetScreenNameLabel: UILabel!
@IBOutlet weak var tweetTextLabel: UILabel!
@IBOutlet weak var tweetCreatedLabel: UILabel!

func updateUI() {

    tweetTextLabel?.attributedText = nil
    tweetScreenNameLabel?.text = nil
    tweetProfileImageView?.image = nil
    tweetCreatedLabel?.text = nil


    if let tweet = self.tweet
    {
        tweetTextLabel?.text = tweet.text
        if tweetTextLabel?.text != nil  {
            for _ in tweet.media {
                tweetTextLabel.text! += " "
            }
            for user in tweet.userMentions{

                    tweetTextLabel.attributedText = NSAttributedString(string:"\(user.keyword)")




            }
        }

        tweetScreenNameLabel?.text = "\(tweet.user)"

        if let profileImageURL = tweet.user.profileImageURL {
            let qos = Int(QOS_CLASS_USER_INITIATED.value)
            dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(qos, 0)) { () -> Void in
                if let imageData = NSData(contentsOfURL: profileImageURL) {
                     dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue()){
                    if profileImageURL == tweet.user.profileImageURL{
                         self.tweetProfileImageView?.image = UIImage(data: imageData)
                        }
                    }}
                }
        }


        let formatter = NSDateFormatter()
        if NSDate().timeIntervalSinceDate(tweet.created) > 24*60*60 {
            formatter.dateStyle = NSDateFormatterStyle.ShortStyle
        } else {
            formatter.timeStyle = NSDateFormatterStyle.ShortStyle
        }
        tweetCreatedLabel?.text = formatter.stringFromDate(tweet.created)
    }

}
```

The problem is here

```
 for user in tweet.userMentions{
                    tweetTextLabel.attributedText = NSMutableAttributedString(string:"\(user.keyword)")

            }
```

I don't know how to color it (attributedText).I have the strings with hashtags ,usernames.there I;m trying with the usernames

Update

```
for user in tweet.userMentions{
                //tweetTextLabel.attributedText = NSMutableAttributedString(string:"\(user.keyword)")
                var attributedText =  tweetTextLabel.attributedText
                var userName:NSString = user.keyword
                var atrString = NSMutableAttributedString(string:tweetTextLabel.text!)
               atrString.addAttribute(NSForegroundColorAttributeName, value: UIColor.redColor(), range: fullString.rangeOfString(userName))
                attributedText = atrString


            }
```

and is saying this ;it was working before : Use of unresolved identifier 'fullString'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
var attrs = [NSForegroundColorAttributeName : UIColor.redColor()]
var atrText = NSMutableAttributedString(string:"text", attributes:attrs)
tweetTextLabel.attributedText = atrText;
```

Comment: This line in swift       var attrs = [NSForegroundColorAttributeName : [UIColor redColor]]

Comment: var attrs = [NSForegrountColorAttributeName:UIColor.redColor()]

Comment: TweetTableViewCell.swift:42:34: '(UIColor) -> $T3' is not identical to 'NSString'

Comment: var attrs  = NSForegroundColorAttributeName(UIColor.redColor())

Comment: This code entirely in swift:

   var atrString = NSMutableAttributedString(string:"Text")
        
        atrString.addAttribute(NSForegroundColorAttributeName,
            value: UIColor.redColor(),
            range: NSRange(location:0,length:atrString.length))

Comment: Thanks,now I want to replace that thing form text and put the colored one

Comment: Are you want select some part of text?

Comment: Yea I select the username from text.But went I do attributedText  = atrString  .I set the text to just the username(attributedText is the whole text

Comment: You need to define range for userName in full string

var userName:NSString = "User name"
atrString.addAttribute(NSForegroundColorAttributeName, value: UIColor.redColor(), range:fullString.rangeOfString(userName))

Comment: fullString - it is mean string which contain userName

Answer (score 2):

Thank you VladZ,But my problem is to get the range for that username,hashtag or url.So Thats my questions now

Answer (score 0):

You can do like this.

```
 NSMutableAttributedString *attributedText = [[NSMutableAttributedString alloc] tweetTextLabel.text];
 [attributedText setAttributes:@{NSFontAttributeName:[UIFont boldSystemFontOfSize:26.0f], NSForegroundColorAttributeName:[UIColor colorWithWhite:0.6 alpha:1.0]} range:range1];
tweetTextLabel.attributedText=attributedText;
```

May help you, Enjoy Coding !!

Comment: Swift code ??.I'm trying my best to translate it into swift

Comment: Thank you now I know how to do it.And I want to vote up,but I can't